# Dynamics AX 2012 - Why do certain tasks in batch jobs use the empty batch group

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I have a question with regards to batch processing in Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012.  I have created a Recalculate stock batch job and assigned it to a batch group.  However, when I looked at the tasks inside the batch job, I noticed that some of these tasks were NOT using the batch group I assigned but the empty batch group.  Why is this please?

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be because it creates batch task helpers from `\Classes\InventCostTaskController\createBatchTasks` which might use the batch group setup on `inventParameters.CloseBatchGroupId` which is on the Inventory Parameters form on the general tab.

The batch you created just starts the tasks.